# Get all entities of same kind as list from Google Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Instead of a query like datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5)), how do you get all the entities of the same kind as a list without a limit?

Comment: What a pain to figure this out. FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults() works.

Comment: Like it or not, there will be a limit - if you don't explicitly set one, the limit will be "as much memory as you have" or "as much execution time as you have". It makes far more sense to explicitly set a limit.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Query gaeQuery = new Query(entityName);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(gaeQuery);
List<Entity> list = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```